# Access to the actual member of a union by address

Tags: c, pointers, struct, unions

I was wondering if can be posible to access the actual member of a union by the union address and not by the `->` & `.` operators. If that is posible, is that allowed?

Comment: sure, it's just a memory location... but the union notation tells the compiler HOW to treat the data you're accessing. consider a union that overlays some `char` types with a `float` - what is the datatype of the memory address you're accessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access the memory of the union using the addressof operation `&(union)`

e.g.

```
union foo {
  int32_t bar;
  int64_t baz;
} afoo;

void * address = &afoo;
```

But the point of a union is to allow transparent access to a 'shared' region of data that composed of different types; if you wanted `char *` access to the data, then you can use a `char *` member, and access the data in that manner.

pretending that the *address is a different type, we can use:

```
int64_t *abar = (int64_t*)address;
printf("%llu\n", *abar);
```

Comment: `afoo.bar = 1000; union foo *address = &afoo; printf("%i",(*address).bar);` Is there a way to access what points `address` without the `->` & `.` operators?

Comment: Very strictly speaking is undefined behavior to cast from a pointer to union, to a pointer to int64_t, though I believe the code will behave deterministically on all known compilers. Just have in mind that the compiler is free to add padding bytes anywhere inside a union, except at the very beginning of it.